# WAIT CONDITION IN BLUEPRISM

Tags: blueprism

I am going through the Foundation training for Blue Prism. I am trying to add a wait condition to a process, but the wait condition option is blurred and can not be set.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! You should familiarise yourself with https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your chances of getting an answer. Please have a read of the page and edit your question to provide more details such as what you've tried, screenshots of what is occurring and any other information you think may assist someone in identifying and helping you with your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Processes do not implement Wait stages. Waits are specifically for object-level application interactions.

If you need to pause execution for whatever reason at the Process level, import the `Utility - Environment` VBO and use the `Sleep` action.

I would recommend you re-read the Foundation Training Guide more closely, as this is addressed directly in the `Object Studio -> Wait` section:

> #### Wait
>
> The Wait stage [is] used to enable a Business Object to pause and wait for an application element. This allows a Business Object to deal with potentially erratic application performance. There are different element conditions to wait for but the most common is simply to wait for the element to exist.